# Passing Arguments to a Fragment via Bundles

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
Bundle params=new Bundle();
params.putBoolean("isNew", true);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.main, Fragment
        .instantiate(LandingScreen.this, "com.fragments.FragmentOne",params)).commit()
```

Now this is Fragment1

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
        return root;
    }
   }
```

Where do i receive the Bundle params, that i sent with when creating this Fragment ?

Kind Regards

Comment: in Fragment `onCreate(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You'll receive `Bundle` in Fragment `onCreate(....)`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     boolean isNew=this.getArguments().getBoolean("isNew");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can get the data where `Bundle` object is accessible as a parameter

1. `onCreate()`
2. `onCreateView()`
3. `onActivityCreated()`

### When you use `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
    String myData=this.getArguments().getString("myData");
}
```

### When you use `onCreateView()`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)     {
    String myData=this.getArguments().getString("myData");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
}
```

### When you use `onActivityCreated()`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String myData=this.getArguments().getString("myData");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you'll use call `getArguments()` in `onCreate()`, which gets called sometime after you instantiate the `Fragment` but before `onCreateView()` and `onActivityCreated()` would get called. However, [as per Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)), if you're calling this from your `Activity` while it's being created, you're not guaranteed that the `Activity` has finished initializing before `onCreate()` is called:

> Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is still in the process of being created. As such, you can not rely on things like the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized at this point. If you want to do work once the activity itself is created, see onActivityCreated(Bundle).

For more information, check out this blog post on Activities and Fragments: http://www.zerotohired.com/2015/02/passing-data-between-activities-and-fragments-in-android.